# Laravel eloquent relationship function name

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, eloquent-relationship

I have 2 table, which is posts and categories. The relationship between posts and categories is many to one. So the code in post class model is like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

With that code the application running successfully.

The problem is, when i tried to change the category function name to categories, and i tried to access the name of category of the post like this :
`Post::first()->categories->name`, laravel give an error like this `Attempt to read property "name" on null in D:\BelajarProgram\CODINGAN\Laravel\application\coba-laraveleval()'d code.`

(edited

the "Post::first()->category" return the category of the post when the eloquent function name is category.
But when i tried to change the name of function like categories and accessing it with "Post::first()->categories", it return a null

)

I have tried to change the name of the function of eloquent relationship in category class model with random name, but i still can accessing it and laravel doesn't give an error. The code of category class model is like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me, why i can change the name of eloquent function in category class model, but can't in post class model ?

Comment: Do you actually have a non-empty field `category_id` in your `$post`?

Comment: $post contain Post::FIrst(), and it have category_id field

Comment: the Post::first()->categories return a NULL, it looks like the table not connected

Comment: could you show your `posts` table structure or migration?

Comment: *relationship between posts and categories is many to one* isn't it many to many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing the following should work:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id', 'id');
}
```

Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: thankss, its working. Can you explain why i need to add the relation field of the the table in the parameter of belongsTo() when i change the name of the function ? in the laravel docs, it says you don't need to add that parameter when you use id as your primary key and following the conventions name.

Comment: Well, I always try to add the column names to the relation but this should also work without defining column names if you've named your columns same as my examples i.e. following the naming conventions. You can find more in this link: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse. Please consider reading it.